# LG touchscreen not getting any input events on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, touchscreen

I have a LG LP156WF7 touchscreen (not a laptop) connected to a system running 
Ubuntu 18.04 kernel 5.3.0-53-generic. But having problems with getting the touch working.

I can find the touch device with `lsusb` (1fd2:5002)

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1fd2:5002  
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04b3:3025 IBM Corp. NetVista Full Width Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 17ef:6019 Lenovo 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:9254 Alcor Micro Corp. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and `xinput -list`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Lenovo Optical USB Mouse                  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Melfas LGD AIT Touch Controller           id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ LITE-ON Technology USB NetVista Full Width Keyboard.  id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

But I'm not getting any events when testing with `sudo evtest /dev/input/eventX`

```
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x1fd2 product 0x5002 version 0x100
Input device name: "Melfas LGD AIT Touch Controller"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 330 (BTN_TOUCH)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 0 (ABS_X)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max     4095
      Resolution      12
    Event code 1 (ABS_Y)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max     4095
      Resolution      21
    Event code 47 (ABS_MT_SLOT)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max        9
    Event code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max     4095
      Resolution      12
    Event code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max     4095
      Resolution      21
    Event code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max    65535
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP)
Properties:
  Property type 1 (INPUT_PROP_DIRECT)
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
```

I've tried `sudo modprobe -r usbtouchscreen` with no luck.

Some other possible relevant information:

```
$ xinput list-props 12
Device 'Melfas LGD AIT Touch Controller':
    Device Enabled (163):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (165): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Calibration Matrix (320):  1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Calibration Matrix Default (321):  1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (285): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (286):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (287):    0, 0
    Device Node (288):  "/dev/input/event11"
    Device Product ID (289):    8146, 20482
```

```
$ dmesg | grep "1-3"
[    4.283350] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    4.434414] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=1fd2, idProduct=5002, bcdDevice= 5.00
[    4.434420] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    4.434423] usb 1-3: Product: LGD AIT Touch Controller
[    4.434426] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Melfas
[    4.476442] input: Melfas LGD AIT Touch Controller Touchscreen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:1FD2:5002.0001/input/input3
[    4.476624] input: Melfas LGD AIT Touch Controller Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:1FD2:5002.0001/input/input4
[    6.869400] input: Melfas LGD AIT Touch Controller as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:1FD2:5002.0001/input/input7
[    7.344774] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 4
[    8.538741] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[    8.688057] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=1fd2, idProduct=5002, bcdDevice= 5.00
[    8.688062] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    8.688064] usb 1-3: Product: LGD AIT Touch Controller
[    8.688066] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Melfas
[    8.700870] input: Melfas LGD AIT Touch Controller as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:1FD2:5002.0005/input/input15
```

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Did you ever get it to work? I have the same problem.